# Excel two way link/Mirroring with automatic data pull

Tags: excel, vba

Im currently building a dashboard and would like to view data extracted from a Pivot table in a different format on another sheet while still being to edit the data, this is the two way link script that im using.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If UCase(Sh.Name) = "SHEET1" Or UCase(Sh.Name) = "SHEET2" Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C4")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If UCase(Target.Parent.Name) = "SHEET1" Then
                Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C4") = Target
            Else
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4") = Target
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is. How to [extract data from a pivot table](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/)?

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having with the code you posted?